# Conditional copying in CUDA, where data vector is longer than stencil

Tags: cuda, thrust

I would like to conditional copy data from vector, basing on stencil vector, which is N times shorter. Every element in stencil would be responsible for N elements in data vector.
Suppose that the vectors look as follows (N=3)

```
data = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}
stencil = {1,0,1}
```

What I would like to get in result:

```
result = {1,2,3,7,8,9}
```

Is there a way to achieve this using functions from Thrust library?

I know, that there is:

```
thrust::copy_if (InputIterator1 first, InputIterator1 last, InputIterator2 stencil, OutputIterator result, Predicate pred)
```

but this doesn't allow me to copy N values from data vector basing on one element from stencil.

Comment: shouldn't the result be `{1,2,3,7,8,9}` ?

Comment: Yes, indeed. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As is often the case, I imagine there are many possible ways to do this.

The approach which occurs to me (using [`copy_if`](https://thrust.github.io/doc/group__stream__compaction.html#ga36d9d6ed8e17b442c1fd8dc40bd515d5)) is to use the `stencil` vector as part of a `thrust::permutation_iterator`, that takes the `stencil` vector and generates the index into it using a `thrust::transform_iterator`.  If we imagine a copying index that goes from 0..8 for this example, then we can index into the "source" (i.e. stencil) vector using a "map" index calculated using a `thrust::counting_iterator` with integer division by `N` (using thrust placeholders).  The copying predicate just tests if the stencil value == 1.

The thrust [quick start guide](https://github.com/thrust/thrust/wiki/Quick-Start-Guide) gives a concise description of how to use these fancy iterators.

Here is a worked example:

```
$ cat t471.cu
#include <thrust/copy.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/permutation_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/transform_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/counting_iterator.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace thrust::placeholders;

int main(){

  int data[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
  int stencil[] = {1,0,1};
  int ds = sizeof(data)/sizeof(data[0]);
  int ss = sizeof(stencil)/sizeof(stencil[0]);
  int N = ds/ss;  // assume this whole number divisible

  thrust::device_vector<int> d_data(data, data+ds);
  thrust::device_vector<int> d_stencil(stencil, stencil+ss);
  thrust::device_vector<int> d_result(ds);
  int rs = thrust::copy_if(d_data.begin(), d_data.end(), thrust::make_permutation_iterator(d_stencil.begin(), thrust::make_transform_iterator(thrust::counting_iterator<int>(0), _1 / N)), d_result.begin(), _1 == 1) - d_result.begin();
  thrust::copy_n(d_result.begin(), rs, std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, ","));
  std::cout << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
$ nvcc -o t471 t471.cu
$ ./t471
1,2,3,7,8,9,
$
```

With the assumptions about `stencil` organization made here, we could also pre-compute the result size `rs` with `thrust::reduce`, and use that to allocate the result vector size:

```
$ cat t471.cu
#include <thrust/copy.h>
#include <thrust/reduce.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/permutation_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/transform_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/counting_iterator.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace thrust::placeholders;

int main(){

  int data[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
  int stencil[] = {1,0,1};
  int ds = sizeof(data)/sizeof(data[0]);
  int ss = sizeof(stencil)/sizeof(stencil[0]);
  int N = ds/ss;  // assume this whole number divisible

  thrust::device_vector<int> d_data(data, data+ds);
  thrust::device_vector<int> d_stencil(stencil, stencil+ss);
  int rs = thrust::reduce(d_stencil.begin(), d_stencil.end())*N;
  thrust::device_vector<int> d_result(rs);
  thrust::copy_if(d_data.begin(), d_data.end(), thrust::make_permutation_iterator(d_stencil.begin(), thrust::make_transform_iterator(thrust::counting_iterator<int>(0), _1 / N)), d_result.begin(), _1 == 1) - d_result.begin();
  thrust::copy_n(d_result.begin(), rs, std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, ","));
  std::cout << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
$ nvcc -o t471 t471.cu
$ ./t471
1,2,3,7,8,9,
$
```